# Exclude ID column from ActiveRecord results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

AR statement:

```rb
Phone.select(:number).distinct.where(in_black_list: true)
```

Results in following MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT number FROM phones WHERE phones.in_black_list = 1
```

A result contains empty IDs:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
  #<Phone id: nil, number: "1234567">,
  #<Phone id: nil, number: "78567459">,
  #<Phone id: nil, number: "78567457">,
  #<Phone id: nil, number: "998567946794567">,
]>
```

How to eliminate these IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` returns Model objects. Your query merely instructs ActiveRecord to restrict the results to include only the `number`. You can pull whatever data you need from the relation. For example, if you want the numbers as an array, you could do that with:

```
Phone.select(:number).distinct.where(in_black_list: true).map(&:number)
# => ["1234567", "78567459", ... ]
```

To avoid having ActiveRecord create model objects, and to request only one column from MySQL, use `pluck`:

```
Phone.distinct.where(in_black_list: true).pluck(:number)
# => ["1234567", "78567459", ... ]
```